# Msbuild does not import Microsoft.Cpp.x64.user options

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, msbuild

I have a x64 C++ project that I want to build from the command line using MSBuild. The project builds fine using VS2013 IDE.

When I try to use MSBuild

```
msbuild  /property:Config=Debug+Release myprj.sln
```

I get compiler errors for missing include files. 
These files are in folders defined in Microsoft.Cpp.x64.user default property file. When I look at the CL command line in MSBuild output, I can see include folders from project's properties are in command line options but folders from Microsoft.Cpp.x64.user are not.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: My crystal ball says that you are building the 32-bit version.

Comment: That was my first thought too but the solution and the projects have only x64 configurations.

Answer (score 0):

The problem fixed itself when I started using a batch file instead of a powershell script.
For reference the correct MSBuild line was

```
msbuild  /p:configuration=release myprj.sln
```

/property:Config=Debug+Release did not work properly.